# Why does chrome has access to google account not firefox?

Tags: chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android

When I go into google accounts on chrome from my android phone , it automatically recognizes the google accounts that exists in my phone. But not when I go there on my firefox browser. Why is it so?

I understand that google owns both android and chrome , but why cant firefox and other browsers dont do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it so?

Because the Chrome developers decided to integrate with the accounts on the phone, to make it easier to log into websites with your Google account. The Firefox developers chose not to add this feature, because it's not as important to them, or because they don't want to add the "use accounts" permission to their app.

> wouldnt it be against some kind of law when it restrict access to one browser not all?

Maybe it would be against some kind of law to do this, but that's not what's going on. Android isn't *preventing* Firefox from adding this feature. Firefox just lacks the feature.